# Fixing incompatible grids in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I've downloaded a raster with temperature projections by the Hadley Center (CIMP5) from [here](https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/search/cmip5/). It comes as a NetCDF file that I loaded onto QGIS 3.2.1. I then overlayed a shapefile with the borders of Peru, and it seems like the two maps are plotted separately:

[image: Administrative border of Peru (left, in gray) and global temperature forecasts]

How should I proceed to plot both the raster (NetCDF) and the shapefile on top of each other as they should? When I first loaded the raster in QGIS I got a message saying the CRS was undefined, but I could not for the life of me find what the appropriate CRS is for these files in the website.

Following @Vince's suggestion, here are the extents of each of the two layers:

[image: Raster info]

[image: Vector info]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the coordinate extent of the two layers. One or both CRS are defined incorrectly.

Comment: Peru is in the right place - the raster is defined on longitudes 0 to 360, not -180 to 180. You either have to add 360 to Peru's longitude, or slice the raster up and put the (180-360) longitude chunk over to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Spacedman's suggestion, I added 360 to the longitude coordinates for the shapefile and they overlayed nicely on top of each other.